# Windows 8.1 freezes after logging in

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, freeze

When I log in, Windows will show desktop quickly, but on the desktop I can not interact with anything, because it will simply do nothing, for example I can right click taskbar and click Task Manager, but it will open only after it unfreezes, which usually takes about 15-30 seconds. While it's frozen most of the icons are blank and after unfreezing they load and also auto-start programs finally begin to load.

I am using AVG 2014, but I don't think that could be the problem, because it was installed for a long time without any problems.

Fast (hybrid) boot is disabled.

What have I tried already?

- running `sfc /scannow` and it
  didn't find any integrity problems.
- disabling all startup programs and services except AVG which can't be disabled
- booting into safe mode worked without freezing!

How can I fix this or find out what is causing this freeze?
Thanks for any answers.

Comment: You say that you have disabled all startup programs, but you haven't said if that made a difference at all - I am assuming that it didn't?  If that is the case, maybe look at any services which could be causing the issue?  Do you have any services that are out of the ordinary - could they have been installed as part of a new application or something?  An even simpler test - does the machine exhibit the same problems when you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: @James I found out that only some system programs are frozen, I can start web broswer or even new explorer window just fine. But for example Windows+S does not open search until it unfreezes.

Comment: @James I think that actually only explorer.exe is frozen.

Comment: Hmm, OK.  The only other thing that I can think of is, a Windows update has been installed that's caused the issue somewhere.  Did the issue present itself after your machine was updated?  It may be an idea to roll your machine back to a time before the issue happened & then install the updates one at a time, this would enable you to avoid installing any problem update(s).

Comment: Well, it installed some updates on 14.11.2015, so it might caused this, but unfortunately meanwhile I wanted to shrink my C: partition and deleted all restore points to make Windows allow me to shrink it more.

Comment: Ah right, off the top of my head, i'm not sure that there is much you can do there then.  There might be an option to uninstall recent updates through the Control Panel - might be worth having a look into that.  If I get some time outside of my Uni work, I will try and have a look into it further and see if there are any other options for you.

Answer (score 1):

NORMAL: This is normal behavior. When you start your machine the most basic information is processed first, like showing the desktop, turning on the graphics, locating the mouse and keyboard drivers, etc. But depending on what you have installed on your computer, virus programs installed, they all get started and some of your programs like Chrome or Desktop shortcuts may have not been initialized during the booting process. Just because you logged in and see your Desktop doesn't necessarily mean that the programs and everything in it is ready to go. It's like getting into a very cold car turning the key and hitting the gas, it might and might not work sometimes a warming up process is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this has been caused by TeamViewer. By disabling the "TeamViewer 14" service, in the System Configuration (msconfig.exe), the problem has been solved.